# Pointer to String Fails to Change Character

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, char

Why is it that I am able to change the element in pointer `p`, but not in pointer `r`? I'm guessing it must do with the properties of pointers.

Changing `p[2]` to `w` makes Gowdbye. Changing `r` crashes the code.

`p`'s address is `0x69fee0`.

`r`'s address is `0x69fedc`.

Both have the same outputs at the for loop (aside from the garbage data after the word 'Goodbye' ends).

```
int main()
{
    char q[]="Goodbye";
    char* p = q;
    char* r = "Goodbye";

    cout<<"Address of p: "<<&p<<endl;
    cout<<"Address of r: "<<&r<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout<<"P["<<i<<"]: "<<p[i]<<endl;
        cout<<"R["<<i<<"]: "<<r[i]<<endl;
    }
    p[2]='w';
    cout<<p<<endl;
    r[2]='w';
    cout<<r<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The difference is that `q` is a (mutable) array which is initialized with a "copy" of string literal `"Goodbye"`, whereas `r` is a pointer to the (immutable) string literal itself. Changing string literals is undefined behaviour (and therefore might crash or do something else).

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this fault is difference between * and [ ]:-

the actual difference is that when we declare *r = “Goodbye”
compiler will place the Goodbye in a read only parts of
the memory and return a pointer to that location which
will be placed in the char pointer and any write operation
will be causing Segmentation fault

but q[] will allocate memory location for the characters
then copy the characters to that location and location
is writeable so any modification is valid.

Comment: There is no guarantee the string literal will be placed in "read-only memory". The C++ Standard simply says that attempting to modify a string literal leads to undefined behaviour.